# If Statement in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, if-statement

I'm having issues writing an If statement in React Native.
I'm building the mobile version of my React Js project where I already have the "if" statement but I'm not being able to write it in Native.

Here is what I got so far:

```
{renderItems && (
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>{return item.date}}
        numColumns={numberOfCols}
        renderItem={({item})=>(

        #######################################
       if (item.copyright "exists" return (
       <Image source(require(a specific local image)/>
        else( return the code below
        #######################################

          <View style={styles.viewpic}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ImageDetails', 
         item)}>
            <Image 
            style={{
    height: 104,
    width: square - 20,
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:'white',
    borderRadius:2,
    
    }} 
    source={{uri:item.url}}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        />)
      }
```

the code works fine without the if part. I tried a few combos with "{" ,"(" ,"({" but nothing worked.

Thanks everyone for your help!
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
{renderItems && 
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>{return item.date}}
        numColumns={numberOfCols}
        renderItem={({item})=>(     
       item.copyright== "exists" ? 
       <Image source(require(a specific local image)/>
       :<View style={styles.viewpic}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('ImageDetails', item)}>
        <Image style={{
                        height: 104,
                        width: square - 20,
                        margin: 10,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor:'white',
                        borderRadius:2,
                        
                        }} 
                     source={{uri:item.url}}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>)}
        
        />
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seem to be some missing brackets. I would create a separate function like `check()` for the `if` statements and let it return the JSX elements instead:

```js
    const check = (item) => {
        if (item.copyright === "exists") {
            return (
                <Image source={require('a specific local image')}/>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.viewpic}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ImageDetails', item)}>
                        <Image style={{
                                height: 104,
                                width: square - 20,
                                margin: 10,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                borderColor:'white',
                                borderRadius:2,

                            }} 
                            source={{uri:item.url}}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    {renderItems && (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(item)=>{return item.date}}
            numColumns={numberOfCols}
            renderItem={({item})=>(
                check(item)
            )}
        />
    )}
```

If you do not want a separate function you have to write the function in the Flatlist's `renderItem` a little bit different:

```js
    <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(item)=>{return item.date}}
            numColumns={numberOfCols}
            renderItem={({item})=> {
                if (item.copyright === "exists") {
                    return (
                      <Component1/>
                    )
                }
                else {
                    return (
                      <Component2/>                
                    )
                }
            }    
        }
    />
```

But still check for the brackets. They should all be correct in the first code snippet though.